# Creation ( if table not exists ) and insertion of table using  a single query in sqlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to use a single query to insert into a table and if that table is not yet created create it and perform the insertion

Any ideas, answers suggestions or sample **queries** are welcome

Advanced thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SQLiteDatabase.execSQL()` command, and execute two queries seperated by ';', like:

```
db.execSQL("create table if not exists('columns and details here');insert into 'whatever you want to insert');"
```

Comment: Hi Aswin I recently found that this query is not working on my device but no problem in AVD have any idea about this issue I am using micromax funbook

Comment: No its not crashing thats still confuses me problem is only the first query is get executed the second one is spiked with out making any error or warning

Answer (score 0):

first you have to ckeck that table is already created or not so use this query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "abcxyz" ( ' +
           '"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,' +
           '"vorname" TEXT,' +
           '"name" TEXT,' +
           '"geburtsdatum" TEXT,' +
           '"suchid" TEXT )'
```

and than write your insert query.